# "rails new" command does not generate public/javascript folder

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

"rails new" command does not generate public/javascript folder with js files there.(and other ways to make rails app dont generate this folder too(for example RubyMine does not generate this folder too) Please help. I am newbie, but didnt find someone to have same problem.

using 3.1.0 rails version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rails s` is supposed to launch the server so it's a good sign :)

Run `rails new app_name`

Comment: i made a mistake in discription. i did rails new. but i dont have public/javascripts diretory in my app(

Comment: Ok, I see, there is no more `public/javascripts` in Rails 3.1. It has been moved to the `assets` folder

Comment: thanks! i was trying to use highcharts. How can i get jquery-1.4.2.min.js i dont have it/ i need to install jrail? or another gems? cause i saw that it generates automaticly , but my app dont have it9

Comment: you have it but it's inside a gem. see in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` there is `//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs`

Comment: so i dont need to have it? it is in application.js? i just need to uncomment them? thanks you for answering my questions)

Comment: the file itself is in the gem an application.js loads it. Check: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: thanks. And the last one question: where i can get rails.js? it's needed for highcharts , but i dont have it. or it's in aplication.js too&

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3.1 generates your public assets under:

```
app/assets/javascripts
app/assets/stylesheets
app/assets/images
```

This is part of the new Asset Pipeline feature, which will precompile your assets into your public folder.

You can read all about the new asset paths in the Rails Guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html